# Having Your Own Copyrighted App Automatically After Publishing

Tags: legal, copyright, business, appstore, google-play

I have a question regarding for the game app and in business. You see, I decided to publish an app to Google Play. When I published it, does this app automatically declared that this app is copyrighted or copyright protected by the publisher and creator like me itself or not? If not, does it have to seek something or required to register this app for copyright authentication via online or at office or not?

Comment: That depends on where you live, but most likely you don't have to register anything. Copyright is automatically assigned on creation. As always, consult a specialized lawyer for advice.

Comment: Is it automatically acknowledged/recognized by users even if he/she didn't see the copyright logo/icon, this app is still copyrighted?

Comment: Yes, at least in the United States. If you google "should I register for copyright?" you will get better and more authoritative answers than in here. You should really try google first, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: The fact that it exists means someone created it, that creator has certain legal rights over their own creation simply because they were the one who created it, i.e. copyright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you create a creative work, you automatically have an exclusive copyright on it. This is guaranteed by various international copyright treates (like the [Berne Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention_for_the_Protection_of_Literary_and_Artistic_Works)) which are recognized by almost all countries worldwide.

In some jurisdictions you can register a copyright for a work (in the USA, you can do so at the United States Copyright Office), but this is optional and not necessarily required to enforce your rights in court when you have other prove that you created the work.

An explicit copyright notice ("Copyright ©2013 John Doe, all rights reserved") is not required either. It is just used as a friendly reminder to people that you are the copyright owner and that you care about your copyright. But such a notice is not required to enforce it, should someone violate it.

When you publish something on google play, you give google a non-exclusive license to distribute your software (otherwise they wouldn't be allowed to publish it). Non-exclusive means that you retain the copyright. You can still publish it yourself, license it to other entities and sue entities which distribute it without your permission.

Comment: So that means no worries. There are some process to take in order to publish apps at Google Play and this app is automatically copyright protected without further notice?

Comment: I saw something from your link you've gave me an it said that under Article 3(4), " `simultaneously" is defined as "within 30 days` ". Is there a limit?

Comment: I would recommend you to read the [original text](http://www.wipo.int/treaties/en/ip/berne/trtdocs_wo001.html#P98_14701) of the convention. This is only relevant for publishing in countries which are not part of the Berne convention - and those are very few. But keep in mind that the Berne convention itself is not a law. The convention is implemented in each participating country with local laws which interprete the convention differently. Check your local copyright laws and those of the United States (because they are the laws which apply to Google).